# Scraping table from data site with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in Python and I stuck with an idea to scrape the whole table from https://wow-pets.com/compare/eu/silvermoon/kazzak
so I started with this:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

WAIT_PERIOD = 20
def make_soup(url):
   thepage1=urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
   thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(thepage1).read()
   sleep(WAIT_PERIOD)
   soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
   return soupdata

petdata=""
soup = make_soup("https://wow-pets.com/compare/eu/draenor/silvermoon")
```

After that what ever I have tried, I couldn't pull the table with petnames, prices etc.
My main goal is to calculate the best ratio and printout the best results.

Any help is appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the site utilizes a script to update the table listings as an examination of the table's structure after a `request.get` call merely yields empty header tags. To work around this, utilize a browser manipulation tool such as `selenium`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import re
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://wow-pets.com/compare/eu/silvermoon/kazzak')
page = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('table', {'class':'table-sortable'})
headers = [i.text for i in page.find('thead').find_all('th')]
main_table = [[c.text for c in i.find_all('td')] for i in page.find('tbody').find_all('tr')]
final_results = [dict(zip(headers, [re.sub('\n+', '', a), *b])) for a, *b in main_table]
```

Output (first ten results):

```
[{'Pet name': 'Hippogryph Hatchling', 'Silvermoon': '499,999', 'Kazzak': '313,949', 'Diff.': '▼ 37%', 'Global price': '668,709'}, {'Pet name': 'Spectral Tiger Cub', 'Silvermoon': '492,711', 'Kazzak': '400,000', 'Diff.': '▼ 19%', 'Global price': '876,368'}, {'Pet name': 'Nightsaber Cub', 'Silvermoon': '304,836', 'Kazzak': '250,000', 'Diff.': '▼ 18%', 'Global price': '671,397'}, {'Pet name': 'Everliving Spore', 'Silvermoon': '301,000', 'Kazzak': '439,993', 'Diff.': '▲ 46%', 'Global price': '691,879'}, {'Pet name': 'Dragon Kite', 'Silvermoon': '297,234', 'Kazzak': '359,987', 'Diff.': '▲ 21%', 'Global price': '628,084'}, {'Pet name': 'Rocket Chicken', 'Silvermoon': '284,053', 'Kazzak': '309,999', 'Diff.': '▲ 9%', 'Global price': '651,913'}, {'Pet name': 'Tuskarr Kite', 'Silvermoon': '278,595', 'Kazzak': '299,998', 'Diff.': '▲ 8%', 'Global price': '635,809'}, {'Pet name': 'Guardian Cub', 'Silvermoon': '267,741', 'Kazzak': '299,999', 'Diff.': '▲ 12%', 'Global price': '716,485'}, {'Pet name': "Landro's Lichling", 'Silvermoon': '247,999', 'Kazzak': '200,000', 'Diff.': '▼ 19%', 'Global price': '565,617'}, {'Pet name': 'Bananas', 'Silvermoon': '239,431', 'Kazzak': '278,711', 'Diff.': '▲ 16%', 'Global price': '540,228'}]
```